# Database and program Design For reservation system

Tags: database-design

I want to write a reservation system.
in sample it has 2 table:

_Classes:
C_ID, C_title, C_quantity

_Persons:
P_ID, P_Name, Class_ID

the reserve should be  continue until  Count of _persons of a class equals C_quantity.

my question is about the best way to check Capacity availability while inserting new person to the class?
is it possible that parallel registering occurred in a busy system?

store procedure ?  triggers ? trans? 
what is most corrected idea?

(C#, SQL server)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say that all solutions workw. If there is ok to use a stored procedure it would be the best way in my opinion. It is possile using triggers, but it is harder to get a good error handling.

There is no need for transactions, as you could join and get one query.

There is a little example with a temptable how you could insert new rows until a maximum. If you do that in a proc or sql statement does not matter, but I think it will be hard using trad EF.

```
    create table #tmp
    (
        id int identity(1,1),
        data int
    )

-- call many times 
    declare @result table (id int )
    insert into #tmp 
    output Inserted.id into @result
    select a.* from 
    (select 1 data ) a
    inner join (select count(*) cnt from #tmp ) c on c.cnt < 5

    -- to get the new row id ( null/empty if full)
    select id from @result
```